# Implement Atmosphere in annotation-driven Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, meteor, atmosphere

I'm currently stuck with this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: MeteorServlet not defined in web.xml`
As my Spring project is completely with annotations configured, I have no web.xml.

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.musicbox")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


...

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AtmosphereArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

The atmosphere resolver. Same as in any examples I could find, but I moved some functions into a utils class.:

```
public class AtmosphereArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        return AtmosphereUtils.getAtmosphereResource(webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return AtmosphereResource.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }
}
```

And the according utils class:

```
public final class AtmosphereUtils {

    public static AtmosphereResource getAtmosphereResource(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return getMeteor(request).getAtmosphereResource();
    }

    public static Meteor getMeteor(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Meteor.build(request);
    }

...

}
```

As I understant this, I have to create a configuration for the meteor servlet. But I couldn't find any examples how to do that... at least not any annotation-driven.

**Edit:** 
My problem is now, I thought the `Meteor.build(request)` would take some kind of default configuration. But it seems, that it needs to be configured in my web.xml (which I don't have). If this is the case, what would be the way to configure meteor with JavaConfig (and what needs to be configured)?

**Edit2:**
Alright, I made it a step further by adding the MeteroServlet at startup, which causes the Atmosphere Framework to get initialized on server startup (shown in log).

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic meteor = servletContext.addServlet("MeteorServlet", new MeteorServlet());
        meteor.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        meteor.addMapping("/meteor");
    }
```

However the problem still persists.

Comment: I don't see a question here?  What's specifically is your problem?  If you're just looking for code, that off-topic here.  If you've got a more specific question, then it would help to state it clearly at the end.

Comment: sorry, edited my question. hope it is clearer now.